# Using tabular in fancyhdr

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, header-footer, fancyhdr

For my header page layout, I use `fancyhdr`. I use `tabular`s in the headers. The following is my code.

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,12pt]{article}

%***************************** preamble region **************************
\parindent=0pt        %leading space for paragraphs
\usepackage{fancyhdr}        %Extensive control of page headers and footers in LaTeX2e

\usepackage[english]{babel}        %use for the below package `datetime'
\usepackage{datetime}        %Change format of `\today' with commands for current time
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{-}
\newcommand{\headertoday}{\the\year \dateseparator \twodigit\month \dateseparator \twodigit\day}

\usepackage[lmargin=2.500000cm,rmargin=2.500000cm,tmargin=2.500000cm,bmargin=2.500000cm]{geometry}        %Flexible and complete interface to document dimensions
%************************************************************************

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.600000}        %coefficent to adjust table line spacing
\lhead{\begin{tabular}[b]{ll}\footnotesize{Statical Calculation}&\footnotesize{}\\\footnotesize{Project: xxxxxx}&\footnotesize{}\end{tabular}}
\rhead{\begin{tabular}[b]{rr}\footnotesize{Date:}&\footnotesize{\headertoday}\\\footnotesize{Page:}&\footnotesize{\thepage}\end{tabular}}
\chead{\begin{tabular}[b]{cc}\footnotesize{}&\footnotesize{}\\\footnotesize{}&\footnotesize{}\end{tabular}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.000000pt}
\headsep=6.000000mm        %the distance of main text to the decorative line
hello\\

\end{document}
```

But the contents of `tabular` doesn't align with the decorative line at both ends. I mean, e.g., the leftmost text should align with the leftmost end of the decorative line. How to fix it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You've forgotten about the intercolumn space in the tabular.

```
\lhead{\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}} ...}
\rhead{\begin{tabular}{rr@{}} ... }
```

(And you mispelled 'statistical'.)

Comment: i just noticed your mention -- my misspell. thanks a lot. i will update all my calculation sheet.

Comment: @Alan i added `settototalheight' to calculate the header height. in this case, the left header aligned to the most left decorative line. but the right header failed. i don't know how to add code in comment, even don't know how to add enter in text:(. so i am not sure if you can understand my meaning.

Comment: @Alan i just learned how to input codes.

`\newcommand\leftheadercalc{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}ll}\footnotesize{Statical Calculation}&\footnotesize{}\\\footnotesize{Project: xxxxxx}&\footnotesize{}\end{tabular}}`

`\newcommand\rightheadercalc{\begin{tabular}[b]{rr@{}}\footnotesize{Date:}&\footnotesize{\headertoday}\\\footnotesize{Page:}&\footnotesize{\thepage}\end{tabular}}`

`\newcommand\midheadercalc{\begin{tabular}[b]{cc}\footnotesize{}&\footnotesize{}\\\footnotesize{}&\footnotesize{}\end{tabular}}`

`\settototalheight\headheight{\maxof{\leftheadercalc}{\rightheadercalc}{\midheadercalc}}`

Comment: @Warem I can't reproduce your problem. Using the code you put in your comment (and the adding `\lhead{\leftheadercalc}`, etc to make the actual header) everything lines up as before. (And you've reproduced the mispelling :-) again.)

Comment: @Alan really? could you please paste your code? in fact, i should paste my code. but i don't know how to do it in comment. by the way, could you tell me how to paste code in comment and how to input enter in comment? every time when i enter in comment, it doesn't input enter instead of posting the current comment. this is why what i input is always in a big paragraph.